# What type of EC2 instance is better suitted for Wso2 CEP Standalone?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

compute optimized (c3, c4) or a memory optimized (r3) instance for running a stand-alone wso2 cep server?

i searched the documentation but could not find anything regarding running this server on ec2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please start again by reading this topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and try to edit the question to be clear for willing helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the WSO2 SA recommendations,

**Hardware Recommendation**

**Physical :**

3GHz Dual-core Xeon/Opteron (or latest), 4 GB RAM (minimum : 2 GB for JVM and 2GB for the OS, 10GB free disk space (minimum) disk based on the expected storage requirements (calculate by considering the file uploads and the backup policies) . (e.g if 3 Carbon instances running in a machine, it requires 4 CPU, 8 GB RAM 30 GB free space)

**Virtual Machine :**

2 compute units minimum (each unit having 1.0-1.2 GHz Opteron/Xeon processor) 4 GB RAM 10GB free disk space. One cpu unit for OS and one for JVM. (e.g if 3 Carbon instances running require VM of 4 compute units 8 GB RAM 30 GB free space)
EC2 : **c3.large** instance to run one Carbon instance. (e.g if 3 Carbon instances EC2 Extra-Large instance) Note : based on the I/O performance of **c3.large** instance, it is recommended to run multiple instances in a Larger instance (**c3.xlarge or c3.2xlarge**).

**NoSQL-Data Nodes:**

4 Core 8 GB (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningHardware_c.html)

**Example**

Let's say a customer needs 87 carbon instance. Hence, they need 87 CPU core / 174GB of memory / 870GB free space.

This is calculated by not considering the resources for OS. Per each machine, they need 1CPU core, 2GB memory for OS.

Lets say they want to buy 10 machines, then total requirement will be 97 CPU core (10 core for OS + 87 core for Carbon) 194 GB memory (20 GB for OS + 174GB for Carbon) 870GB free space for carbon (Normally, storage will have more than this).

Which means, each machine will have 1/10 of above and can run about 9 carbon instances. i.e roughly 10 CPU core / 20 GB Memory/ 100 GB of free storage

Reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines

Note: 
However, everything depends on the what you're going to process using CEP. therefore, please refer @Tharik's answer as well.

Comment: this was helpful!, sorry for late marking as answer

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of processing CEP node does. CEP node requires alot of memory if the processing event size is large, or the event flowing through put is high and if there are time windows in the queries. For those cases Memory Optimized EC2 instances are better as those provide lowest price for RAM size. If there are a lot of computation on algorithms you have extended you might more processing capabilities of compute optimized instances.